# Access character at specific index in a string in Fortran

Tags: arrays, string, fortran, character

Is there a way to access a character in a string in fortran? If I wanted to store the first letter of a the string "taco" in a character variable how would I do that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Character variables and constants can be "substringed" using a syntax similar to an array section.

```
a_character_variable = "taco"(1:1)
```

A substring of a character variable is also a variable - it may appear on the left hand side of an assignment statement.