# "PROCEDURE attribute conflicts with INTENT attribute" when compiling simple Fortran program with module

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran90

I have a simple Fortran 95 program

```
include "sandboxlib.f95"
program sandbox
    implicit none
    write(*, *) 'abc'
end program
```

and a simple module containing a function

```
module sandboxlib

 integer, parameter :: dp = kind(1.d0)

contains
function cumsum(mat, m, n) result(c)
    implicit none
    real(dp), intent(in) :: mat
    integer, intent(in) :: m, n
    integer i, j
    real(dp), dimension(m, n) :: c

    c(:, 1) = 0.d0

    do i = 2, m
        do j = 1, n
            c(i, j) = c(i-1, j) + mat(i, j)
        end do
    end do
end function
end module
```

I compile `sandbox.f95` with this command

```
/usr/bin/gfortran -O -std=gnu -Wfatal-errors -pedantic -Wall sandbox.f95 -o sandbox
```

which results in this error

```
sandboxlib.f95:6.23:
    Included at sandbox.f95:1:

    function cumsum(mat, m, n)
                       1
Error: PROCEDURE attribute conflicts with INTENT attribute in 'mat' at (1)
```

I looked around and found a [few](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8413337/2766558) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36487824/2766558) that discuss modules, functions, etc. or an error like this, but I can't figure out why this won't compile.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your `mat` is declared scalar

```
  real(dp), intent(in) :: mat
```

but you use it as an array

```
  c(i, j) = c(i-1, j) + mat(i, j)
```

and the compiler parses this as a function call and assumes `mat()` is a function. And functions cannot have `intent`.

I assume the correct thing to do is to make `mat` an array in the declaration. Something like

```
  real(dp), intent(in) :: mat(:,:)
```

or

```
  real(dp), intent(in) :: mat(m,n)
```

With the former you can avoid passing `m` and `n` as arguments.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the help. `mat(m, n)` fixes the error. Related question to what you said, though: if I use `mat(:, :)` instead, and therefore don't pass in `m` and `n`, I'll still need to calculate the dimensions inside the function, right? Otherwise the `do` loop won't work?

Comment: @MichaelA You are right, you have to. Check `size()` and `lbound()` and `ubound()`. Sometimes the sizes can be global (module) variables, where it makes sense to share it this way.